# Runtime compiler is not loaded with Angular 8 and lazy module

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I've created a new Angular 8 project with @angular/cli -> ng new, added a new lazy module, with *ng serve* is working fine, **but with ng build --prod** it raises the following error:

[image]

Here is my app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Here is my app-routing.module.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: () => import(`./dashboard/dashboard.module`).then(m => m.DashboardModule),
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Here is my dashboard.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    DashboardRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    DashboardComponent,
  ]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

Here is my dashboard-routing.module.ts

```
const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(ROUTES)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule { }
```

This is my tsconfig.json (default)

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think I've solved the issue, the problem was with this line:

```
loadChildren: () => import(`./dashboard/dashboard.module`)
```

I was using the backticks, replacing them with the normal single-quote '', it works fine.

Comment: It seems as though double quotes are not allowed either...my AOT build was breaking when we used double-quotes. For anyone else that is frustrated!

Answer (score 6):

this syntax worked for me:

```
{ path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'}
```

Comment: This syntax is no longer valid for the latest version of Angular (v9), a new spec was provided in version 8. https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and solved it by having my loadchildren in just one line, and not many (because of 120 caracts limit on my sonar !)
I'm using Angular 10

Ko :

```
{
    path: "my-big-page",
    loadChildren: () => import("./pages/path-to-page/path-to-page/path-to-page/" +
    "ppage.module").then(
    m => m.MyPagePageModule),
},
```

Ok :

```
{
    path: "my-big-page",
    loadChildren: () => import("./pages/path-to-page/path-to-page/path-to-page/ppage.module").then(m => m.MyPagePageModule),
},
```

The string in the import must be a strict string !